# React.js onSubmit addNewUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, onsubmit

Why addNewUser is not a function ?

> TypeError: addNewUser is not a function

Here is the problem, when i complete my form and click save show `addNewUser` is not a fuction.

```
const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

// Here the problem when i complete my form and click save show addNewUser is not a fuction. 

    addNewUser({
        id: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
        name,
        age,
        phone,
        address,
        type,
    });
    setName('');
    setAge('');
    setPhone('');
    setType('');
    setAddress('');
    closeModal();
};
```

```
    return ( 
        <Form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
        <Form.Controller>
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}></input>
        </Form.Controller>
        <Form.Controller>
            <label htmlFor="age">Age</label>
                <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Enter Your Age" value={age} onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}></input>
        </Form.Controller>
        <Form.Controller>
            <label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" value={phone} onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}></input>
        </Form.Controller>
        <Form.Controller>
            <label htmlFor="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Enter Your Address" value={address} onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}></input>
        </Form.Controller>
        <Form.Controller>
            <label htmlFor="type">Type</label>
            <input type="text" id="type" placeholder="Enter Your Type" value={type} onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}></input>
        </Form.Controller>
        <Row>
            <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
            <Button type="reset">Reset</Button>
        </Row>
    </Form>
    );
```

Comment: Where is addNewUser defined?

Comment: There's no way with the given information that we could figure out what 'addNewUser' is. If you have the capacity to set a breakpoint at that bit of code, I recommend you do that. If no breakpoint, you can log as much information as possible about the type and properties of 'addNewUser' so you can try to figure out what it is defined as, if not a function, so you can find out the origin of your problem.

Comment: why you have written  addNewUser({
        id: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
        name,
        age,
        phone,
        address,
        type,
    });


what is the purpose of this block of code

Comment: there is addNewUser

    const addNewUserHandler = (data) => {
        setState((prevState) => setState([...prevState, data]));
    };

            <Modal show={showModal} hide={() => setShowModal(false)}>
                <AddUser addNewUser={addNewUserHandler}></AddUser>
            </Modal>

Comment: @Geekyvinayak
to save form inputs to multi states and make new information and new id

Comment: @TKoL This is my code in GitHub you should see app.js and adduser.js https://github.com/HassanFathy10/React.app.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is missing much needed data, however after inspecting you GitHub repo I believe I've understood your issue.

The `AddUser` is used in two places.

```
App
 └ Modal
   ├ AddUser (1)
   └ Overlay
     └ AddUser (2)
```

You pass the `addUserHandler` function correctly to the first instance of `AddUser` (1). But since `children` isn't used in `Modal` that instance isn't rendered. Instead the second instance of `AddUser` is rendered. For this instance you don't pass the `addNewUser` property. Hence it gives you the *TypeError: addNewUser is not a function* error.

Reference: https://github.com/HassanFathy10/React.app/blob/a8cd6f19c46d0f545bfcf191d3348a9c13eb5ecc/src/App/App.js

Comment: You made my day! thank you very much I put children in modal.js and remove adduser and worked thank you again